# Convert mht to image C#

Tags: c#, html, image, internet-explorer, mhtml

hay all.
we are using 'AxWebBrowser' to convert html to images but when we are using it to convert mht we get the scrollers bars in the images, can anyone tells us how to remove the scrollers ? how about the webBrowser on the .net frame works is it better to use ? 
does any one have a good product that can do this on run time in the code and can be distributed ?

Comment: we used dynamic pdf in the end

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this question pop-up a few times on Stackoverflow.  One solution that works pretty well, albiet a bit dated, is the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/IECapture.aspx